# Cannot show image in toast

Tags: android, image, toast, illegalargumentexception

I want to show an image in a Toast in Android. In my layout.xml, I have defined a LinearLayout 'svllid', that contains a textview and a tablelayout, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/llid">
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/cpuText"  
        android:hint="Enter cpu" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </EditText>
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/ramText"  
        android:hint="Enter ram" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </EditText> 
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/bandwidthText"  
        android:hint="Enter bandwidth" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </EditText> 
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/imageRequestButton"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Download"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:onClick="sendImageRequest">  
    </Button>       
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/svllid">
        <TextView android:text="client profile"
            android:id="@+id/profileName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#000000">
        </TextView> 
        <TableLayout
            android:paddingBottom="3pt"  
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="3pt" 
                    android:paddingTop="3pt" 
                    android:text="Image Name"
                    android:layout_width="150px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="3pt" 
                    android:text="blah.png"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_width="315px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageName"/>          
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="3pt" 
                    android:text="Size"
                    android:layout_width="150px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="3pt" 
                    android:text="155kb"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_width="300px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageSize"/>          
            </TableRow> 
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="3pt" 
                    android:text="Dimensions"
                    android:layout_width="150px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <TextView
                    android:paddingLeft="3pt" 
                    android:text="250 X 150px"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_width="300px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageDimension"/>         
            </TableRow>                         
        </TableLayout>                                          
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to show the LinearLayout with id ***'svllid'*** in a Toast and show the toast from my activity code.

Now, in the actual android code, I first call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Subsequently, I read an image from a soap message. I then create an ImageView and I want to insert it into the LinearLayout 'svllid' and show that LinearLayout in an Android Toast.

```
                Toast imageToast = new Toast(this);
                LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.svllid);
                toastLayout.addView(image,1);
                imageToast.setView(toastLayout);
                imageToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                imageToast.show();
```

However, it won't work. My application crashes with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I guess you cannot do it this way. Your svllid is already in the activity. You cannot add it to the toast again.. may be you need to create a new view programmatically or `inflate` another layout and then `setView()` for the toast.

Comment: So should I take the 'svllid' out of the main.xml and create it programmatically instead?

Comment: yes. keep it in a separate xml. Use `LayoutInflator` to inflate the new xml and then set it to the toast. OR create it programmatically and set it to the toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use a specific ID for the root layout. You have to name it "toast_layout" or "toast_layout_root" (not sure which one has to be used- the documentation is slightly ambigious there, try both).

And as Varun said you need to put the layout in its own layout file.

Read the [Android Doc's and follow the given example.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView)

Answer (score -1):

For this you can use custom Toast to display image.

Refer [This](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-toast-example).